# Delete and backspace not working in ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

I accidentally mashed a couple of keys together at the same time and now delete and backspace no longer work inside code blocks on aspx pages. ReSharper functionality such as autocomplete (Alt+Enter) is still working just fine. I've tried

```
devenv /resetuserdata
```

but with no luck. With ReSharper disabled everything works just fine but I much prefer coding with it turned on.

I should mention I'm using ReSharper 4.5

I have tried upgrading to the latest version (4.5.1288.2 at time of writing)

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ReSharper

I have uninstalled ReSharper, reset all user settings in Visual Studio, deleted all files in

C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\JetBrains

and reinstalled ReSharper. Still no joy.

Update: Problem only occurs on pages that are not included in the open solution (a developer forgot to include them) but are present in the solution's folder structure. Obviously I have solved my problem by including the necessary files but now I'm going to see if I can recreate this on another machine.

Comment: I have the same option.  I used the resharper demo.  The worrying thing is this happened after I uninstalled resharper.

Answer (score 1):

And you checked that the keys aren't bound to a command somewhere? All bindings can be found in Tools -> Options -> Keyboard. I did the same thing once, and some of my buttons started acting wierd. I fixed it by tracking down the keybinding and deleting it in the preference menu.

Comment: It's a good suggestion but I have tried resetting all key bindings.